# Error when printing integer within string

Tags: java

I am new to Java and was following a book with the following code...

```
class Vehicle {
    int passengers;
    int fuelcap;
    int mpg;

    int range() {
        return mpg * fuelcap;
    }

    double fuelneeded(int miles) {
        return (double) miles / mpg;
    }
}

class TwoVehicles {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Vehicle minivan = new Vehicle();
        Vehicle sportscar = new Vehicle();
        double gallons;
        int dist = 252;

        minivan.passengers = 7;
        minivan.fuelcap = 16;
        minivan.mpg = 21;

        sportscar.passengers = 2;
        sportscar.fuelcap = 14;
        sportscar.mpg = 12;

        gallons = minivan.fuelneeded(dist);
        System.out.println("To go ", + dist + " miles minivan needs " + gallons + " gallons of fuel.");

        gallons = sportscar.fuelneeded(dist);
        System.out.println("To go ", + dist + " miles sportscar needs " + gallons + " gallons of fuel.");
    }
}
```

However, upon running this code I get an error saying 'error: no suitable method found for println(String,String)'. Why is this happening?

Comment: Remove comma after `"To go ",`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `System.out.println` with **2** arguments, pass it only **1** String.

The comma  that is not inside the String (After the String `"To go" ,`), is telling the compiler to treat the Strings as 2 different arguments.

Change this line:

```
System.out.println("To go ", + dist + " miles minivan needs " + gallons + " gallons of fuel.");
```

to this:

```
System.out.println("To go " + dist + " miles minivan needs " + gallons + " gallons of fuel.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the presence of comma(,) outside the string your code is showing error

```
System.out.println("To go ", + dist + " miles minivan needs " + gallons + " gallons of fuel.");
```

Your code should be

```
System.out.println("To go ," + dist + " miles minivan needs " + gallons + " gallons of fuel.");
```